Dependency Conflicts with drf-haystack==1.8.13 and djangorestframework==3.15.0
I recently upgraded my Django version from 4.0 to 4.2, which necessitated an upgrade of djangorestframework to version 3.15.0 due to compatibility issues (Django REST Framework 3.15.0).
However, I'm encountering a dependency conflict with drf-haystack. The latest version of drf-haystack (1.8.13) has a requirement for djangorestframework to be <=3.14. Here is the warning I'm receiving:
Warning!!! Possibly conflicting dependencies found:
* drf-haystack==1.8.13
    - djangorestframework [required: >=3.7,<=3.14, installed: 3.15.0]

Is there a way to resolve this dependency conflict without downgrading djangorestframework?
Would forking drf-haystack and adjusting its dependencies be a viable solution?
I tried downgrading djangorestframework to 3.14 but I am skeptical about its compatibility with Django 4.2 as Django's 4.2 version is not mentioned in the requirements of  djangorestframework==3.14
https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/3.14.0?tab=readme-ov-file#requirements
